# Исходники Draft Service Description

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Draft Service Description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuK-o24lWMU)

помогите пожалуйста найти(написать) исходники того что на видео
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuK-o24lWMU